# File path autocompletion options?

Tags: front-end, autocomplete

Suboptions like "FileCompleteEnable" in CodeAssistOptions are new in v10.
Are there any options I can exercise with respect to the behavior of filepath autocompletion?

[image]

Then is there anyway to set the default behavior to sorting behavior for file completion? For example, by **date created**, by **reverse lexicographic order**, etc...

Support for patterns would be useful too, e.g.  `Import@"~/Downloads/*.(gif|png)`.